# Interfaces for Command Pattern in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns, command-pattern

Is there a library out there that already provides the interfaces we need for the command pattern in Java?

For example:

```
 public interface Func1<T,R> { public R execute(T input); }

 public interface Func2<T1,T2,R> { public R execute(T1 input1, T2 input2); }

 public interface Predicate1<T> { public boolean execute(T input); }

 ....
```

Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't look like a command pattern library, this looks like a functional programming library.

Comment: Try Guava, they have `Predicate` and might also have those others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) has your first and third interfaces (called `Function` and `Predicate`). Your second one, IMHO, is not useful, because you would just have to combine T1 and T2 in a single object, and use the first interface instead.

More interesting, Guava also has a whole lot of methods *using* these two interfaces, like `Iterables.any(Iterable, Predicate)`, `Iterables.transform(Iterable, Function)`, etc.